# Chromebook lxde barebones fix

Tags: 14.04, lxde, chromebook, crouton

I recently decided to install lxde on my hp 14 chromebook (arm) and when crouton finished installing I got an extremely barebones version of lxde. I have heard that there are lines you can type I  the terminal to get the "full" version of it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please forward your question to here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: also, run `apt-cache search lubuntu | grep lubuntu` to see available packages and see here on how to use apt-get https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: **Note to the close voters:** Crouton is just another boot-loader, so once Crouton got Ubuntu up-and-running, it's just plain old Ubuntu (without grub) and **questions about Ubuntu are on-topic!** (Though questions *about the Crouton boot-process itself* are off-topic...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would execute the following, since you're sounding like you might require the full desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```